# running Javascript through IE via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, windows, internet-explorer-8

I need to run a javascript code on server side using IE8
(the javascript works with activeX objects)
But I need to run it from command line, from PHP.

So in short, I will install apache + php on 2003 Windows server, and php will use system() to execute iexplore running a page of javascript.

I would like to know if this is logically possible, as i can see a number of pitfalls:

1. PHP might not be able to execute iexplore without a user logged in.
2. iexplore might not run the javascript correctly to interact with ActiveX objects
3. iexplore might not quit when JS finished running.

I will attepmt to make a little test case as soon as i can, but any pointers about this aproach will be apreciated.

Edit:

Now, I realise that this is a round about way of doing things (read, wrong), The goal was to make a Dymo Label printer print from a central location rather than client machines (this is where the JS is from). Dymo SDK provide several ways of interacting with their printers, but Im still looking for a way to use pure PHP. I think it might be possible to use one of their example cli binaries.

Comment: @yarek: Apologies for my candidness, but what you are proposing sounds truely insane. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps the community can suggest a more sensible way of attaining your goal.

Comment: agreed with @spender -- sounds like something Heath Robinson might have invented if he'd been a programmer. (ActiveX? Is anyone still using that in the browser? I thought it had been consigned to the dustbin of really bad ideas a least five years ago)

Comment: PHP has a **lot** of control over the system on which it's running. Anything you can do with ActiveX you can do with PHP

Comment: It is indeed a "crazy thing to do", as im told by several people now. But i never knew that PHP supports COM related stuff. I will certainly try that first. @steven_desu if you can word your comment into an answer i would be happy to accept it. The original idea was to run the already created block of javascript wasting as little time as possible

Comment: @Yarek Well I can't exactly phrase my comment as an answer without knowing **what** your javascript is supposed to do.

Comment: @steven_desu Ahh, good point. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Dymo have a way of interacting with it from Command Line? If so you can easily send commands to it via `shell_exec()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

This is generally the easiest option when you are able to control something via command-line. Sometimes you need a bit more control, however (interactive command-line programs, for instance) and sometimes the program you want to run isn't even command-line based. In these cases you may need `proc_open()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) or `exec()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Just make sure that if you use `exec()` you **redirect the output!!**. Failure to do this can cause the program to hang indefinitely.

From the PHP manual:

> **Note:**
>
> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update your Service Packs and AntiVirus definitions. I can foresee many many many potential security issues here.

Keep in mind that JavaScript in IE runs with a webpage context.  When you refresh/navigate pages, the old JavaScript execution state is wiped and a new one begins.

Was there a specific question here?

Comment: Running IE in the context of a service account that *should* have limited rights is a vulnerability out-of-the-box, if it will even work at all. Don't do it.

Comment: Not really an issue as everything is generated locally and controlled, there is absolutely nothing interacting with public.